# Rest API em PHP - como trabalhar com rotas termindas em .json?

Tags: php, json, api, restful

Eu estou criando um web service Restful em PHP. Não estou usando nenhum framework.

Estou seguindo as recomendações de padrões ou boas práticas para o desenvolvimento de web APIs, [sugeridas pela Casa Branca](https://github.com/WhiteHouse/api-standards).

No site deles, já na primeira linha, encontramos a seguinte recomendação de uma URL para recuperar um recurso:

```
List of magazines:
GET http://www.example.gov/api/v1/magazines.json
```

Então eu não entendi como vai funtionar essa URL terminada em ".json", pois todas as páginas do projeto deveriam terminar em ".php" correto?

O mais próximo que consegui foi

```
http://www.example.gov/api/v1/magazines.json.php
```

mas mesmo assim a terminação ".php" precisa ser incluída na URL ou no código que vai consumir o serviço.

Então fica minha pergunta:
Como fazer uma URL que termina em **.json** ser reconhecida pela URL ou código API para apontar para o lugar certo que vai tratar da requisição e retornar um JSON?

Comment: Com certeza essa tipo de endereço: `http://www.example.gov/api/v1/magazines.json` são rotas criadas mas, como você está fazendo sem framework  pode terminar `.php` sem problemas!

Comment: Virgilio, obrigado, eu nem me dei conta disso. Então essa rota '.json' deve ser parte de alguma aplicação usando um framework, que por sua vez deve fazer alguns tratamentos ( que combinam '.htaccess' e/ou a variável '$_SEVER' por exemplo). Se eu quiser fazer ".json" ser responsível teria que trabalhar com '.htaccess' e/ou '$_SERVER' tbm, correto?

Comment: `.json` no caso ai de rotas são nomes, e pode ser qualquer nome (tem um padrão em alguns framework, mas, no geral pode ser qualquer nome) isso te confundiu um pouco eu acredito, mas, não se preocupe se você fizer `http://localhost/c.php` se retornar o dados corretamente é o que importa! o que mais importa é a segurança e o retorno do json !

Comment: ok. valeu. posta lá a sua resposta